# clearing memory to create a new item

Tags: java

how do I clear my memory after the fifth action?
to be able to create a new basket again and fill it with new balls.

Because now, when you re-create the basket and fill it with balls,
the error appears on the second action (filling the basket)

how to clear the cache with the first bucket so that you can enter the second one?

//main

```
public class Dialogue {
private static Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

private static boolean buildBasket = false;
private static boolean completedBasket = false;
private Basket basket;
private static int volumeOfBasket = 0;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    boolean buildBasket = false;
    boolean completedBasket = false;
    Basket basket =null;
    int volumeOfBasket = 0;
    try {
        while (true) {
            System.out.println("1 - build а basket");
            System.out.println("2 - add balls to basket");
            System.out.println("3 - output information about basket");
            System.out.println("4 - weight of balls in the basket");
            System.out.println("5 - quantity red balls");

            int i = ScunnerInformation.checkInformatio();

            if (i == 1) {
                System.out.println("what max count of ball will into basket?");
                volumeOfBasket = ScunnerInformation.getVolumeBasket();
                Basket newBasket = new Basket("<Basketballs>", volumeOfBasket);
                System.out.println("Basket was build with name: " + newBasket.getNameBasket() +
                        " and with the size " + newBasket.getVolume());
                buildBasket = true;
                basket = newBasket;
            } else if (i == 2) {
                if (buildBasket) {
                    basket = WorkWithBasket.fillBasket(basket);
                    completedBasket = true;
                    System.out.println("you have successfully added balls to the basket");
                }else {
                    System.out.println("error");
                }
                } else if (i == 3) {
                if (completedBasket) {
                    WorkWithBasket.InfoOut(basket);
                } else {
                    System.out.println("error");
                }
            }else if (i == 4) {
                if (completedBasket) {
                    System.out.println("weight basket: " + WorkWithBasket.countWeight(basket));
                } else {
                    System.out.println("error");
                }
            }else if (i==5) {
                if (completedBasket) {
                    System.out.println(WorkWithBasket.countRedBalls(basket) + " it it number of red balls");
                } else {
                    System.out.println("error");
                }
        } else if (i == 6) {
            break;
        }
    }

    }finally {
        if (scanner!=null){
            scanner.close();
        }
    }
}
```

//fillBasket

```
public class WorkWithBasket {

public static Basket fillBasket(Basket basket){
    for(int i =0; i < basket.getVolume(); i++){
        Ball temp = new Ball(Color.getRandomColor(), WorkWithBall.CostBall(),WorkWithBall.WeightBall());
        basket.addBall(temp);
    }
    return basket;
}
```

//addBall

```
public void addBall(Ball ball){
    if (ball !=null){
        basket[ball.getId() -1] = ball;
    }
}
```

[image: error]

//basket initialization

```
public class Basket {
private Ball[] basket;

public Basket(){
    this.basket = new Ball[this.volume];
}

public Basket (String nameBasket, int volume){
    this.basket = new Ball[volume];
}

public Ball[] getBasket(){
    return basket.clone();
}
public void addBall(Ball ball){
    if (ball !=null){
        basket[ball.getId() -1] = ball;
    }
}
```

Comment: The code you provided won't even compile. `backet` variable is an object and you try to access it as if it was an array. Probably variable `backet` inside of `addBall` is something else than the one declared in the `main`. We need to know how you initialize it before adding balls.

Comment: @Amongalen added initialize

Comment: Did you try debugging your code? It seems that `ball.getId()` returns 5 while `backet` is an array of size lower than 4. Why - it can't be told with the current code you provided.